# Why do dictionaries give me different pronunciations?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

I'm looking up in various dictionaries for IPA phonetics of words, but some  dictionaries give me different pronunciations for **"ei"**.

For example, lets look up for **breit**:

- [Hueber](http://www.hueber.de/woerterbuch/online/) and [adaba](http://www.aussprache.at/) say it is pronunced: **[braet]**
- [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/german-english/breit), [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/breit), [Pons](http://de.pons.eu/dict/search/results/?q=breit&l=deen&in=&lf=de), [thefreedictionary](http://de.thefreedictionary.com/breit) and [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/translate/german-english/breit) say it is pronunced: **[brait]**
- [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/breit) gives **[breit]**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outside of IPA many companies and organizations use their own system to express phonetics, so somewhere on their website there should be a key to their pronunciation system.

One thing I noticed is that **Hueber** is seated in Munich, **adaba** are from Austria. Therefore some influence from Bavarian dialect may be the cause of a different pronunciation recommendation, even though in Bavaria *"breit"* is pronounced more like **[broàd]**.

Duden, and Pons both reference the "ARD-Aussprachedatenbank", which is the standard pronunciation recommended for the TV stations.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that they just chose a different representation for the same diphthong. You may want to read [this paragraph in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_phonology#Diphthongs), even though it lacks a citation.